# Command line print for printing pdf does not work on windows 2012

Tags: java, windows, pdf, command-line, printing

I am using following command to send the pdf files to the printer

```
print /d:<<printer_name>> <<file_name>>
```

This works fine on my windows 7 machine. But when tried it on windows server 2012 it does not print the pdf file. It was showing Java printing to printer's printing tray but didnt generate any output.

Is there anything that is blocking the file to be printed in windows server 2012.
Also some threads suggests that the above print command only works for text file.. but it works for me to print pdf files on windows 7, so i am assuming it should also work on windows server 2012